# Site showing version 4.1.16 as latest version

Tags: upgrade

Someone I know has a WP site that is running 4.1.16 and I advised to upgrade it to 4.7.3

Weirdly though it is showing 4.1.16 as the latest version. Apart from solving this by doing a fresh install of 4.7.3, any suggestions on how to kick start an auto upgrade?

[image]

Comment: You say you manually installed 4.7.3 and it shows 4.1.16? Did you delete wp-admin and wp-includes before uploading the latest version?

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow - no, you are minsunderstanding me.  I am wondering if someone has an idea on how toget 4.1.16 to realise it isn't the latest version, if not I will have to do a manual install of 4.7.3

Comment: Right, I have only ever seen this happen when the website was infested with malware. I'd just do a fresh install and reset the salts, and passwords.

Comment: Gotta love when people downvote a decent question but don't bother to explain why.

Comment: I got your back buddy :)